# Creating columns by subaggregating by condition in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have following table:

```
id1 | id2  | n_products | daydiff
 a  |   1  |       12   |    12
 a  |   1  |       11   |    13
 a  |   1  |       90   |    46
 a  |   2  |       5    |    5
 b  |   2  |       15   |    15
 b  |   2  |       15   |    21
 c  |   3  |       90   |    7
```

I need to aggregate this table by `id` and using `daydiff` in the following manner:

- if `daydiff` is less than 14
- if `daydiff` is between 14 and 28
- if `daydiff` is more than 28.

this should be aggregated using mean.

The result should be:

```
id1 |    id2  |  sub 14 | 14_28 | 28+
 a  |     1   |    11.5 |    0  |  46
 a  |     2   |    5    |    0  |  0
 b  |     2   |    0    |    15 |  0
 a  |     3   |    7    |    0  |  0
```

How can I achieve this? I guess this would involve some `group by` statements, but I am not sure how should they be applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon's answer is cross platform correct, but for myself I prefer the snowflake [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) syntax

```
SELECT id1, id2,
    AVG(IFF(datediff < 14, n_products, NULL)) as avg_lt14,
    AVG(IFF(datediff >= 14 and datediff <= 28, n_products, NULL)) as avg_14_28,
    AVG(IFF(datediff > 29, n_products, NULL)) as avg_29pl
FROM t
GROUP BY id1, id2;
```

Comment: @johnnyheinekin . . . Do you really prefer non-standard functions such as `IIF()` to *standard* SQL constructs such as `CASE`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  and Simeon : How to do if I want all unique levels in daydiff to be column names and corresponding values will be 0 or 1. It is just like one hot encoding but one row(grouped by id1, id2) can have multiple 1s. I dont want to use  column n_product. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id1, id2,
       avg(case when datediff < 14 then n_products end) as avg_lt14,
       avg(case when datediff >= 14 and datediff <= 28 then n_products end) as avg_14_28,
       avg(case when datediff > 29 then n_products end) as avg_29pl
from t
group by id1, id2;
```

Some databases calculate the averages of integers as an integer. I don't know if Snowflake does this.  If so, then change `n_products` to `n_products * 1.0`.

Comment: snowflake returns 3dp floats